# Система ролей в приложении

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, role

Возник такой вопрос. Имеется веб-приложение. Нечто вроде Википедии. В нем содержится много статей, а также есть пользователи, которые могут эти статьи просматривать, редактировать и удалять. Пользователи делятся на группы (или роли), этих групп пока две - пользователи и администраторы (но могут появиться и новые). Далее, у статей есть две характеристики - тип (для каждой статьи он может быть один) и теги (их у статьи может быть много). Имеется таблица типов, а в таблице статей есть поле TypeId, представляющее собой foreign key на таблицу типов. С тегами несколько иначе - таблицы тегов нет, а у каждой статьи есть поле Tags в котором хранятся теги, разделенные запятой (да, я знаю, что денормализация, и что это плохо, но вот так сложилось). 
Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать какую-то систему позволяющую ограничивать права пользователей (и групп) на доступ к конкретным статьям, а также к статьям определенного типа или тега. То есть нужна какая-то система, позволяющая разграничивать права доступа в любых комбинациях: например, запретить группе Пользователи просматривать статьи с тегом "Tag", запретить пользователю с id 10 редактировать статьи с типом 5, запретить пользователю с id 10 просматривать статью с  id 20 и тд. То есть нужна возможность задавать ограничения для пользователя/группы  на просмотр/редактирование/удаление статей по идентификатору/тегу/типу.

Я решил сделать как-то так:

1. Создать таблицу пользователей users (для простоты пусть там будет id и name)
2. Создать таблицу ролей Roles (id, name)
3. Создать таблицу разрешений Permissions(???)
4. Создать таблицу-связку UserRoles (userId, roleId)
5. Создать таблицу-связку ролей и разрешений RolesPermissions (RoleId, PermissionId)

Но тут возникают трудности. Я не знаю, что записать в таблицу разрешений. Дело в том, что разрешения довольно разношёрстны. Ведь могут быть разрешения на статьи по их типу, на статьи по их тегам или на конкретные статьи, а сами разрешения выдаются как пользователям так и группам.

У меня есть два варианта для таблицы Permissions:

1. В каждой строке таблицы Permissions хранить флаги IsPagePermission (указывает, что это разрешение применяется к конкретной статье), IsTypePermission (указывает, что разрешение применяется к типу) и IsTagPermiss. Это плохо тем, что вводятся три флага, причем для каждой строки один из флагов должен быть выставлен, а два других сняты (и это надо отслеживать). Кроме этого должен быть столбец, в котором хранится id статьи или id типа или тег, на который распространяется данное разрешение. При этом если id статьи и id типа имеют тип int, то тег представляет собой строку (то есть тип столбца должен быть variant).
2. Создать еще одну таблицу PermissionTypes, в которой будут храниться типы разрешений (разрешение на тип статьи, на тег или на конкретную статью). А в таблице Permissions завести столбец PermissionTypeId. В данном случае нет необходимости заводить три флага в таблице Permissions и отслеживать, что значение true имеет только один из них. Но при этом всё равно остаётся необходимость в поле variant.

Второй выглядит предпочтительнее но при этом есть ещё проблема с полем variant (выглядит коряво) и еще есть проблема с разграничением для пользователей и групп. Либо придется делать две RolesPermissions (разрешения, задаваемые для ролей) и UsersPermissions (разрешения, задаваемые непосредственно для конкретных пользователей, как бы "поверх" тех разрешений, которые пользователи получают с ролями) либо вводить в таблицу RolesPermissions признак того, что это разрешение выдается роли или пользователю.

Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту таблицы Permissions и к двум таблицам RolesPermissions  и UsersPermissions. Хотел бы спросить вашего совета, как тут быть? Может есть варианты получше или я чего-то не учел?

Comment: Я так понимаю пользователь может обладать несколькими ролями одновременно. Тогда надо будет решить еще вопрос, если одна роль говорит что можно, а другая, что нет - то какое решение принять. Плюс к этому если роль говорит нельзя, но есть отдельное разрешение этому конкретному пользователю - то видимо можно. т.е. напрашивается вопрос приоритета запрещений/разрешений что бы на основе них вычислить эффективное

Comment: И кстати, не хотите сделать роли специальным видом пользователя ?

Comment: @Mike этот вопрос решён (наверное мне стоило бы указать это в тексте). Если у пользователя есть хотя бы одно разрешение, то система должна считать, что можно. Скажем, если пользователю запрещены к просмотру статьи с каким-то тегом, но при этом разрешена какая-то конкретная статья, имеющая этот тег, то он может читать (или редактировать или удалять, смотря на что есть разрешение) эту статью, но не другие с этим тегом

Comment: И от variant надо по любому избавится - завести справочник тегов, пусть у них то же будут id. даже пусть они по старинке будут у статьи текстом перечислены, но скажем, триггер на таблицу статей может при записи может вести справочник тегов, т.е. добавлять в него новые записи и может быть заодно заполнять таблицу id_статьи-id_тега, что бы по ней было проще вычислять права

Comment: У статей id небось обычный identity, есть возможность переделать его на генерацию триггером, на основании sequence ?

Comment: @Mike избавиться от variant надо бы (и перенести теги в отдельную таблицу) но это зависит не от меня к сожалению, так что я вынужден делать так, как это описано

Comment: Ну т.е. вы будете парсить строку тегов каждый раз при поиске прав. в принципе это конечно ничего не меняет, только запрос вычисляющий эффективные права усложняет. вместо того что бы тупо сравнить id или в крайнем случае сам текст но конкретного тега, придется разбирать строку на куски и получать отдельные теги, хотя конечно можно like, но full scan таблицы прав доступа тогда гарантирован

Comment: Все таки очень важный вопрос дадут ли вам роли сделать видом пользователя. тогда вы избавляетесь от таблицы ролей и работаете только с пользователями.

Comment: Ну а так - как бы вы там не разруливали с тегами и прочим, второй вариант гораздо красивее. хотя и типы прав скорее чисто номинальная таблица. все равно в запросе вычисляющем права все эти типы будут захардкодены ибо от них зависит откуда из записи статьи брать информацию для сравнения с записью прав. Я бы вообще их какими нибудь буквами обозначил для наглядности, а не id.

Comment: хотя если удастся перейти на sequence при генерации id статей, то id для тегов (все таки чисто для прав завести) и типов статей брать из одного источника и тогда про типы прав вообще можно забыть, а огульно из записи статьи собирать все id для прав и тупо сравнивать с таблицей прав

Comment: @Mike я не уловил, а в чем смысл делать роли видом пользователей?

Comment: Запрос получения прав проще. выборка из единственной таблицы где id-субъекта = пользователю или одной из его ролей. не надо всяких union прав ролей и прав пользователя

Comment: @Mike я если честно не понял, как это вообще должно работать, сам принцип такого "объединения"

Comment: Ну буквально `select sum(x) from статьи, права where права.субъект IN(select $ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ union select группа from userRoles where пользователь=$ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ) and права.объект IN(статьи.id, статьи.тип)` ну там конечно еще добавятся извращения для тегов и возможно какая то приоритезация. Ну первый IN возможно в join переделать, а может даже второй в свете проверки тегов